# Replace option of Select with Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Good morning, I am trying to replace the options of each Select the check box to be able to give a better style and improve the functionality that it fulfills but when changing it for Check box it does not fulfill the function that it does with the option, The function that it fulfills is the Search for selected tags in each Select, It is for Blogger.

I am looking to get you to click on the selected checkbox in each Select. But I have not been successful, I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

```html
<div class="tabs-outer">
    <div class="tabs-cap-top cap-top">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fauxborder-left tabs-fauxborder-left">
        <div class="fauxborder-right tabs-fauxborder-right"></div>
        <div class="region-inner tabs-inner">
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol">
                <div class="widget HTML" id="HTML3">
                    <h2 class="title">Buscador Avanzado</h2>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <div id="multi-search">
                            <select class="cmbColumn" id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn[]" multiple>
                               <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="acción+" />1
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="Checkbox" name="cmbColumn[]" value="TV" /> TV
                            </select>
                            <select class="cmbSidebar" id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar[]" multiple>
<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV+" />1
<input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbSidebar[]" value="TV" /> TV
                            </select>
                            <select class="cmbColor" id="cmbColor" name="cmbColor[]" multiple>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" />1
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" /> TV
                                <input type="checkbox" name="cmbColor[]" value="TV" /> TV
                      </select>
                            <input class="filtro" onclick=" getValue() " value="Filtrar" type="button" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <span class="widget-item-control">
                            <span class="item-control blog-admin">
                                <a class="quickedit" href="//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID=4472703516037708465&amp;widgetType=HTML&amp;widgetId=HTML3&amp;action=editWidget&amp;sectionId=crosscol" onclick=" return _WidgetManager._PopupConfig(document.getElementById(&quot;HTML3&quot;)); " target="configHTML3" title="Edit">
                                    <img alt="" src="http://img1.blogblog.com/img/icon18_wrench_allbkg.png" height="18" width="18" />
                                </a>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tabs section" id="crosscol-overflow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom">
        <div class="cap-left"></div>
        <div class="cap-right"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue() {
        var valcmbColumn = document.getElementById("cmbColumn").value;
        valcmbSidebar = document.getElementById("cmbSidebar").value;
        valcmbColor = document.getElementById("cmbColor").value;
        valOutput = (valcmbColumn + valcmbSidebar + valcmbColor);
        window.open("/search/label/" + valOutput, "_self");
    }

    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == "block") {
            e.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            e.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script></div>
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, a checkbox is not a valid child of a select.  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element

Comment: A `<select>` element must contain `<option>` child elements. If you want what you are attempting, you'd have to create your own drop down component.

Comment: Thanks for answering, on this occasion how could I make it work ?, It works correctly using `Option` and without the brackets, but with checkbox it doesn't read what is in the values

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Scott Marcus, you would have to make your own drop down component to add checkmarks to a sort of select.

Something like this:

Just make the span element look like a select option and make it clickable instead of on hover if you so desire.

You could also style the selections div to your own liking.

```css
.selections{
  transform:scaleY(0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  transform-origin:top;
  height:0;
}
.selector{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.selector:hover .selections{
  transform:scaleY(1);
  height:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:200px;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selector"><span style="border:1px solid red">Hover me and style me as select</span>
  <div id="selections" class="selections">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Something" /> Something <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="Something" /> Something <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="Something" /> Something <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="Something" /> Something <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="Something" /> Something <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: implement the code but when doing the search, it gives me the result "undefined"